# objects.create(...) does not create the objects

Tags: python, django

For some reason my objects aren't being created:

```
def upload_view(request):
    key = f'{request.user}-{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}'
    for file in request.FILES.getlist('fileToUpload'):
        TemporaryImage.objects.create(image=file, key=key)
    return HttpResponse('complete')
```

`TemporaryImage.objects.all()` returns an empty QuerySet, and when I inspect the database, nothing is there, yet I can see the HttpResponse being returned successfully. I don't see any errors.

The same is true when I do:

```
tmp_img = TemporaryImage(...)
tmp_img.save()
```

What could be the cause?

@EDIT:

I just realiased that `request.FILES.getlist('fileToUpload')` is empty.

Comment: What happens when you print `TemporaryImage.objects.create(image=file, key=key)`?

Comment: Ok now can you show the result of `print(request.FILES)`

Comment: @CalebGoodman empty, too.

Comment: What did you change from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257125/attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-committed) question, aside from getlist?

Comment: @CalebGoodman see my newest question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258428/request-files-is-empty