# request.FILES is empty

Tags: python, django

I have a form with an `<input type="file">` for selecting images to upload, and once upload button is clicked, a POST XMLHttpRequest is sent which calls the `upload_view` that should save the images on the server. However, my `request.FILES` is empty for some reason. When I `console.log(document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files` I can see the files there. And my `request.POST` looks like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'fileToUpload': ['[object FileList]'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['bOjUFzTnMVbHOWOQURj2egJuRizsVJIBMSfQra4yuz7MX3DOEaRPHbMVnY8xyIsU']}>
```

My view:

```
def upload_view(request):
    key = f'{request.user}-{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}'
    for file in request.FILES.getlist('fileToUpload'):
        TemporaryImage.objects.create(image=file, key=key)
    return HttpResponse('complete')
```

My JS:

```
function uploadFile() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files);

  var value = [];
  document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken').forEach(function(x) {
      value.push(x.value);
  })

  fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', value[0]);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("POST", Urls['upload-view']());
  xhr.send(fd);
}
```

My form:

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload</label>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Unless you made a typo somewhere, I'm guessing this is a bug.  The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) for this explicitly state that *"POST does not include file-upload information. See FILES."*

Comment: @CalebGoodman I don't think it's a typo. When I do this: `fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0])`, i.e. include only one file, I am able to find it in `request.FILES`.

Comment: Try putting your data in an Array constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append each file individually.

```
var fd = new FormData();
var files = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files;
for (var x=0; x < files.length; x++) {
    fd.append("fileToUpload", files[x]);
}
```